# Roles.GetRolesForUser always takes admin as username

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, admin, membership-provider, roleprovider

I have following code in controller for login validation:

```
SecurityProvider securityProvider = new SecurityProvider();
if (securityProvider.ValidateUser(UserName, Password))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName.ToString(), false);
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole("admin"))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Admin");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "User");
    }
}
```

I have custom membership provider and role provider classes. So, the following method is being called within `Roles.IsUserInRole("admin")`

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
    List<string> currentUserRoles = new List<string>();
    using (myDBEntities db = new myDBEntities())
    {
        currentUserRoles.Add(db.Users.First(m => m.UserName == username).Role);
    }
    return currentUserRoles.ToArray();
}
```

But whatever the username I am trying with, the username that is coming to this method is "admin". There are no traces of setting username explicitly as "admin" in the project. Am I missing anything?

### Edit:

`User.Identity.Name` always returns "admin"

Comment: hum if you always check with `Roles.IsUserInRole("admin")` it's quite logic that you always have "admin" as username in your method. Could you show how do you call `GetRolesForUser()` ?

Comment: I'm not calling the GetRolesForUser method explicitly. But when I am debugging Roles.IsUserInRole("admin"), it is taking me to GetRolesForUser method.

Comment: @KrishnaSarma - Use Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, roleName) instead. See my answer below for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling following overloaded method in `Roles`:

```
Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, roleName);
```

See the difference, we are here passing the userName. And that will eventually be passed to your `GetRolesForUser` method. I think it will solve your problem.